# Moving the elements of an array

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a program that moves the elements of an array from right to left and then prints them, but the only thing that the program prints is the last value: why?

```c
int main (){
    int n = 5;
    int array[n];
    int i = 0;
    int temp = 0;
    while (i < n) {
        printf("Insert the values\n");
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
        i++;
    }
    i = 0;
    temp = array[i];
    i = n-1;
    while (i > 0) {
        i--;
        array[i] = array[i+1];
    }
    i = 0;
    while (i < n) {
        printf("%d\n", array[i]);
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Example of input and expected output:

```
Input: 1,2,3,4,5
Output: 2,3,4,5,1
```

Comment: What exactly do you provide as input, what do you expect as output, and what do you get instead?

Comment: I'll edit the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the loop

```
i = n-1;
while (i > 0) {
    i--;
    array[i] = array[i+1];
}
```

The value of the last element is written to the second last element, and after that the value of the second last element (now the value of the last element) is written to the third last element. The other elements will also get the value of the last element like this.

The order of process should be reversed like this:

```
i = 0;
while (i+1 < n) {
    array[i] = array[i+1];
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but what i have to do if i want that the first value that the user put in become the last one?

Comment: @Sub0Zero1990 Add `array[n-1] = temp;` after the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Step through your code. You start off with the last element, and copy it to the second to the last element. Say the elements are {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}. This means that array[3] before you enter the loop is 4, but after the first iteration, is 5 (`array[i] (4)]` = `array[i+1 (5)] (5)`). Then you move down to array[2], and set it to array[3], which is now five. This repeats for the whole array, until all elements contain 5 (the last value). By the way you aren't even using `temp`, did you intend to do something with it and forget?

Answer (score 1):

You have to preserve the first element of the array (array [0]) in a temp variable then shift the array elements from 0 to n-2, then you will have to insert the first element (array [0]) at the index of last element array [n-1]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (){
int n = 5;
int array[n];
int i = 0;
while (i < n) {
    printf("Insert the value :");
    scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    i++;
}
int temp = array[0];
i = 0;
while (i < n-1) {
array[i] = array[i+1];
i++;
}
array[n-1]=temp;
printf("\n\n");
i = 0;
while (i < n) {
    printf("%d\n", array[i]);
    i++;
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want to move elements to the left, you must first put i in the temporary variable because the value of this variable must remain to move to the previous elements.

```
   i = n-1;
    while (i >1) {
        temp = array[i-1];
        array[i-2] = temp;         
        array[i-1] = array[i];
        i--;
    }
```